# syslog.1 and kern.log.1 filling up with same message

Tags: kernel, disk-usage, log, syslog

So I just recently installed Ubuntu and today I discovered, that my kern.log and syslog files in /var/log/ are way to big (16.5GB and 13.0GB). I started to look into this, and discovered that the culprit was presumably the following line, which is spamed like a million time in both files.

```
kernel: [ 6292.136835] usb 3-1: cannot submit urb 0, error -2: endpoint not enabled
```

I have absolutely no idea what causes this and I am also wondering how to stop that from happening?

Also, can I delete those two files, since they take up a lot of space and if yes how (can't right click and delete them).

EDIT: To clarify, the sound-card that caused the problem was the Kingston HyperX Amp and after not finding out on how to make it work, I returned it.

Comment: What is the USB device 3-1? You can check by `lsusb`.

Comment: Unplug all of your unnecessary USB devices and see if the problem with the logs stops. Reconnect one USB device at a time and see if the problem returns.

Comment: @Pilot6 Well I see a list now but how do I know which one is the device 3-1? Is 3 the bus and 1 the device number?

Comment: @heynnema I'll try doing it, but I already think, that my sound-card is causing the problem since it sometimes just stops working and then I have to reconnect it.

Comment: Is your sound card a USB device?

Comment: @LetsFailNoob That's correct. Bus 3 device 1. Please post the output of `lsusb` to your question if you are in doubt.

Comment: @heynnema yes and removing it seemed to solve those logs. Since it didn't work properly anyway I'll return it and thus the problem should be fixed. Since I am pretty new to this forum, can I close this question or mark it as solved?

Comment: @Pilot6 As I thought, it was the USB souncard (at least no new entry got created with the same message after removing it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a USB sound card that caused the log entries. Removing the sound card stopped the log entries.

Answer (score 6):

This is a problem with some USB device (Bus 3 Device 1).

It must be a hardware issue.